# Vector dot product unsing c

Tags: arrays, function

Im having 2 problems.
first the program doesn't prompt me to enter the second vector, 2nd it is not giving me the input i put in for the first vector.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define SIZE 10
#include <string.h>
int main()
{
    int Vx, Vy, i, j;
    int vector[SIZE];

    printf("Enter 1st vector (q to quit) " );
        for (i=0;i<SIZE;i++)
    {
        scanf("%d", &vector[i]);
    }

    printf("Enter 2nd vector (q to quit) " );
        for (j=0;j<SIZE;j++)

    {
        scanf("%d", &vector[j]);
    }
    printf("\nYou entered");
    printf("\n%d\n", vector[i]);
    printf("%d\n", vector[i]);

    printf("Their dot product is; %d", vector[i] * vector[j]);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: In the `scanf()`s the format should be `"%d"`

Comment: I can't see how the compiler can really compile this code.
ie. The poster is lying that it really runs but not as expected

Answer (score 0):

I see three things immediately you need to change:

```
#define SIZE 10

for (i=0; i<SIZE; i++)

for (j=0; j<SIZE; j++)
```

I have no idea how your compiler treats undefined defintions, but you're setting the vector size to... nothing? 0?